# How to best show that $f(a)$ is the greatest element of $f[A]$

Tags: order-theory

**Prove**
Let $A$ and $B$ be ordered classes,and let $f:A\to B$
be an increasing function.
Prove that if $a$ is the greatest element of $A$, then $f(a)$ is the greatest element of $f[A]$

**Attempted Proof**

By definition, $ x \leq a $ for every $x\in A$

Then $f[A]=\{f(x)|x\in A\}$
Since $f$ is increasing then $ x \leq a \to f(x) \leq f(a) $

Thus $f(a)$ is the greatest element of $A$.

I feel something is missing.
Any help would be appreciated.
I thought of doing it by contradiction

Comment: Hint: What is the if-then statement that represents being the maximum?

Comment: It follows direction by definition.  $f$ increasing means that if $a > b$ then $f(a) \ge b$ and that if $a$ is $\ge x$ for all $x\in A$ then $f(a) \ge f(x)$ for all $f(x) = f(A)$.  There's really nothing more to say and  I can't possibly imagine what you think could be missing.

Comment: When I post stuff here , my proofs I find are incomplete when I think otherwise. Thus when I did this one I felt something was missing.

Comment: Okay, but maybe you should tell us *why* you feel it's incomplete.  There is *nothing* lacking and I can not think of any reason you think there is, so there is *nothing* I can say to help you....  Okay, well you do say "Thus f(a) is the greatest element of A" when you mean "Thus f(a) is the greatest element of f(A)" but other than that, I can't see how that is anything but obvious even to a big dope.

Comment: Um ok, I might check how others prove similar theorems and when I do a theorem and post it & the reasoning doesn’t look similar I will doubt if it is correct